# Why my recursive function is not giving thr correct output

Tags: c++, recursion

This is the problem

> Consider a money system consisting of n coins. Each coin has a positive integer value. Your task is to calculate the number of distinct ordered ways you can produce a money sum x using the available coins.
> For example, if the coins are {2,3,5} and the desired sum is 9, there are 3 ways:

```
2+2+5

3+3+3

2+2+2+3
```

and this is the c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const long long mod = 1e9 + 7;
long long solve(vector<long long>& coins, long long a, long long target, long long count) {
    if (target == 0 && count < a) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (target < 0 || count > a - 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    long long ans = 0;
    for (long long i = count; i < a; i++) {
        ans += solve(coins, a, target - coins[i], count + i);
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    long long a;
    cin >> a;
    long long target;
    cin >> target;
    vector<long long> coins(a);
    for (long long i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> coins[i];
    }
    long long ans = solve(coins, a, target, 0);
    cout << (ans) % mod;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the test case

```
3 5
1 2 3
```

The output should be 5 but I am getting 4 where am I wrong?

Comment: Glad to see all the previous comments on this question were cleared out.

Comment: This is a dynamic programming problem, at least from the description I understand that it is a very common dynamic programming problem - coin change. But your code is not following the dynamic programming approach, it is kind of greedy. I am afraid this solution will not pass if the test input set is strong enough.

Comment: Yes, this is a dp question, I will apply dp here but this recursive relation of mine is not working so there is no use in adjusting it for larger cases. If this was right adapting this for every test case is easy.

Comment: Thanks, every one I found the mistake my recursive function is not correct, just made the recursive tree and realised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this block of code:

```
if (target == 0 && count < a) {
    return 1;
}
```

Should really be this:

```
if (target == 0 && count <= a) {
    return 1;
}
```

That fixes your test case. But it may or may not be your only bug.

I have no idea what this modulo arithmetic is doing or why `% mod` is even warranted.

```
cout << (ans) % mod;
```

Just needs to be:

```
cout << ans << endl;
```

While this is OK:

```
if (target < 0 || count > a - 1) {
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think you need to check for `count > a-1`. Because your subsequent for loop won't do any recursive calls when `count >= a`.

Comment: when the actual answer could be too big to fit in a built-in integer type, programming puzzle sites often stipulate giving the answer modulo 1000000007.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI - You mean to say... "on overflow, give a wrong answer". :)